# Frida - Windows native app - Read a structure exposed by Wininet.h

Tags: windows, wininet, frida

I hook the function **HttpSendRequestExA** of a native Windows application using Frida but I cannot achieve to read the structure **INTERNET_BUFFERSA** passed via the parameter **lpBuffersIn** of this function:

Signature of the function **[HttpSendRequestExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpsendrequestexa)**:

```
BOOLAPI HttpSendRequestExA(
HINTERNET           hRequest,
LPINTERNET_BUFFERSA lpBuffersIn,
LPINTERNET_BUFFERSA lpBuffersOut,
DWORD               dwFlags,
DWORD_PTR           dwContext
);
```

Structure **[INTERNET_BUFFERSA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/ns-wininet-internet_buffersa)**:

```
typedef struct _INTERNET_BUFFERSA {
DWORD                     dwStructSize;
struct _INTERNET_BUFFERSA *Next;
LPCSTR                    lpcszHeader;
DWORD                     dwHeadersLength;
DWORD                     dwHeadersTotal;
LPVOID                    lpvBuffer;
DWORD                     dwBufferLength;
DWORD                     dwBufferTotal;
DWORD                     dwOffsetLow;
DWORD                     dwOffsetHigh;
} INTERNET_BUFFERSA, *LPINTERNET_BUFFERSA;
```

This is the function of the hooking script:

```
  onEnter: function (log, args, state) {
  log('###### HttpSendRequestExA() ###################');
  log("lpBuffersIn  = " + args[1].readPointer());//I'm stuck here to reach the structure
  log('###############################################');       
 }
```

I have searched on Internet but I do not found how to read the pointer an associate it to the expected structure.

Thank you very much in advance for any help or hint :)

Comment: There is a similar example how to handle structs. See section **Parsing the ELF** on the following page: https://versprite.com/blog/application-security/frida-engage-part-one-building-an-elf-parser-with-frida/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the architecture was not specified, the following answer is for a 32-bit process but the 64-bit changes are explained.

The struct `_INTERNET_BUFFERSA` is presented as `LPINTERNET_BUFFERSA` which is a pointer. `args[1]` holds the pointer to the `_INTERNET_BUFFERSA` struct and when read with `.readPointer` what is returned is the value of `dwStructSize` which is **40** for a 32-bit process and **52** for a 64-bit process.

The offsets for each member are:

```c
typedef struct _INTERNET_BUFFERSA {
DWORD                     dwStructSize; // Offset: 0
struct _INTERNET_BUFFERSA *Next; // Offset: 4
LPCSTR                    lpcszHeader; // Offset -> 32-bit: 8, 64-bit:12
DWORD                     dwHeadersLength; // Offset -> 32-bit: 12, 64-bit:20
DWORD                     dwHeadersTotal; // Offset -> 32-bit: 16, 64-bit 24
LPVOID                    lpvBuffer; // Offset -> 32-bit: 20, 64-bit 28
DWORD                     dwBufferLength; // Offset -> 32-bit: 24, 64-bit 36
DWORD                     dwBufferTotal; // Offset -> 32-bit: 28, 64-bit 40
DWORD                     dwOffsetLow; // Offset -> 32-bit: 32, 64-bit 44
DWORD                     dwOffsetHigh;// Offset -> 32-bit: 36, 64-bit 48
} INTERNET_BUFFERSA, *LPINTERNET_BUFFERSA;
```

With this in mind, the following FRIDA code will retrieve every struct member for a 32-bit process:

```js
Interceptor.attach(Module.getExportByName(null, "HttpSendRequestExW"), {
    onEnter (args) {
        let internetBufferStruct = args[1];
        console.log("Struct size: " + internetBufferStruct.readPointer());
        console.log("*Next: " + internetBufferStruct.add(Process.pointerSize).readPointer());  
        console.log("lpcszHeader: " + internetBufferStruct.add(Process.pointerSize * 2).readPointer());  
        console.log("dwHeadersLength: " + internetBufferStruct.add(12).readPointer());  
        console.log("dwHeadersTotal: " + internetBufferStruct.add(16).readPointer());  
        let dwBufferLength = parseInt(internetBufferStruct.add(24).readPointer());
        console.log("lpvBuffer: " + internetBufferStruct.add(Process.pointerSize * 5).readCString(dwBufferLength));  
        console.log("dwBufferLength: " + dwBufferLength);  
        console.log("dwBufferTotal: " + internetBufferStruct.add(28).readPointer());  
        console.log("dwOffsetLow: " + internetBufferStruct.add(32).readPointer());  
        console.log("dwOffsetHigh: " + internetBufferStruct.add(36).readPointer());  
    }
});
```

`Process.pointerSize` is **4** for 32-bit processes and **8** for 64-bit processes and this allows to resolve offsets correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much, it help me a lot.